# how to secure app and source code in heroku

Tags: heroku

I pushed my apps into Heroku, say that Heroku account can be logged in by another user, how to prevent that user from messing up my apps, and even better if can prevent that user from downloading source code? In short, is there another layer of security for apps per different users once they logged in same Heroku account?

At the company level, you need to share with others, right? I'm worried someone else may mess an app, and I'll get blamed.

Comment: Dont share your heroku account.

Comment: Your account _is_ the layer of security. Why would you share it?

Comment: well, at company level, you need to share w/ others, right? I'm worrying about they may mess up w/ apps being used by everyone, and I'm the one to be blamed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the company level, you need to share with others, right?

Don't share your *account*. Every user should have their own account.

Share your *apps*.

You can create [a Team](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams) for your company. Apps can then be owned by the team, and users can be assigned roles for each app the Team owns. You can even [transfer apps from your personal account to the Team](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams#transferring-apps) after creating it.

Comment: thanks Chris, well, sounds like Team is the solution, w/ my limited knowledge of Heroku, here's my understanding:
1) I create another Heroku account @ company level, w/ me as administrator
2) transfer apps from my personal account to this company account
3) add others (mainly IT and/or developer, not actual app users) to Team, and assign them proper permissions to my apps

my further questions as below:
1) i don't have to add actual app users into Team in order for them to use those apps, right?
2) at which permission level others can modify my apps even download source code?

Comment: @bim2016, I suggest you read the entire page I linked to. It covers some of what you are asking. (1) You don't have to create a new Heroku account. You can simply [create a Team from your existing account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams#setting-up-your-heroku-team). (2) Yes, I would transfer the apps to the Team. (3) Yes, [add developers and choose their role](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-teams#managing-permissions).

Comment: I believe all types of collaborators can view or download your source code. If you are concerned about what they do with it you should include that in whatever contract or agreement you have with them.

Comment: thanks Chris, I'll read the links and explore more on Heroku, very appreciated for your help!